# How to click on the confirm button from the console in the metamask

Tags: javascript, console, metamask

I found the item

```
<button class="button btn--rounded btn-primary page-container__footer-button" data-testid="page-container-footer-next" role="button" tabindex="0">Confirm</button>
```

Selected the class

And I run the code in the console

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button btn--rounded btn-primary page-container__footer-button')[0].click();
```

But this code doesn't make the button click.
In other cases this code works

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` expects a *single* class of a *single* element. Use `querySelector()` along with a valid CSS selector instead: `document.querySelector('.button.btn--rounded.btn-primary.page-container__footer-button').click()`